# renamed a table and am getting errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I named a table `Types` and realized that it is a reserved word, so I renamed it 'Category`.

Now when I try to do an ActiveRecord query, I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "categories" does not exist
LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"categories"'::regclass
                                          ^
:               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                     pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                  ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
               WHERE a.attrelid = '"categories"'::regclass
                 AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
               ORDER BY a.attnum
```

I have gone back though all my code and changed all the relation names, model, controller, etc...but I don't know where this error is coming from. Or what it means. Here is my category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :projects

end
```

here is categories_controller.rb:
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController

```
        def create
            @category = Category.new(category_params)
            if @category.save
                redirect_to root_path
            else
                redirect_to({:controller => 'application', :action => 'home'}, :notice => 'Account not created! Something is fishy.')
            end
        end

end
```

and here is what I am trying to do inside the user model (because i want the code to read along the lines of `current_user.contributions_by_category`

```
def contributions_by_category(array)
    category = {}
        array.each do |subarray|
            name = Category.find(subarray[1].category_id).project_category;
            category[name] = 0 unless category.include?(name)
            category[name] += subarray[0] unless subarray[0] == nil
        end
    category
    end
```

also, inside of my project model i have:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'user_id'
    belongs_to :category, :foreign_key => 'category_id' #should change this to a has one association
    has_many :users
    has_many :payments
    has_many :updates
    has_many :comments
    has_one :imapct 

....

end
```

Before I switched the name, I was able to make this query work in rails console as well as rendering it to the screen, so the relation exists, all I did was change the name.

Any help is appreciated!

UPDATE:

here is my table data from rails console:

```
   List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  |    Owner    
--------+-------------------+-------+-------------
 public | categories        | table | seinnaidess
 public | comments          | table | seinnaidess
 public | entrepreneurs     | table | seinnaidess
 public | impacts           | table | seinnaidess
 public | payments          | table | seinnaidess
 public | projects          | table | seinnaidess
 public | schema_migrations | table | seinnaidess
 public | update_comments   | table | seinnaidess
 public | updates           | table | seinnaidess
 public | users             | table | seinnaidess
```

and here is my schema:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150930040619) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "category_type"
  end

  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "entrepreneurs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.text     "about"
    t.string   "location"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.float    "repayment_rate"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "impacts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "ppl_hired",            default: 0
    t.integer  "ppl_schooled",         default: 0
    t.integer  "improved_housing",     default: 0
    t.integer  "improved_nourishment", default: 0
    t.integer  "improved_medical",     default: 0
    t.integer  "community_resource",   default: 0
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "payments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.float    "amount"
    t.integer  "cc_num"
    t.integer  "exp_month"
    t.integer  "exp_year"
    t.integer  "cvs"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "comments"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "url"
    t.text     "description"
    t.float    "money_needed",     default: 0.0
    t.float    "money_raised",     default: 0.0
    t.float    "interest_offered", default: 0.0
    t.datetime "end_date"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "update_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
  end

  create_table "updates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text    "content"
    t.string  "url"
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.string  "date"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "user_name"
    t.string   "password_digest"
    t.string   "impact"
    t.text     "pic_url"
    t.text     "quote"
    t.integer  "payment_id"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.boolean  "admin"
  end
```

Comment: What is the state of your database?  Try running `rake db:reset`

Comment: will do! what does a reset do?

Comment: Per the rails docs, "The rake db:reset task will drop the database and set it up again. This is functionally equivalent to rake db:drop db:setup.": <http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#resetting-the-database>

Comment: i got a `NameError: uninitialized constant Type`

Comment: are you sure the database has the table `categories`?

Comment: What are the contents of your `db/schema.rb` file?

Comment: it has `category` that must be it!

Comment: What exactly is the new table name supposed to be? Is it `Category`, `categories`, `category`, or something else? The error message is telling you that Rails is looking for `categories` (based on the class name of `Category`) but there is no `categories` table.

Comment: well I am referencing a category. I originally named it `category` I forgot that the table name must be plural, so it should be `categories`

Comment: I went back to test this, and since i ded a reset, i have to reseed. I am getting an error `$ rake db:seed
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Type
/Users/seinnaidess/giving_tree/db/seeds.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:seed
(See full trace by running task with --trace)`

Comment: I am going to update my answer with the table data from console and the schema, if you guys do not mind taking another look?

Comment: `categories` is definitely what you want to name your table.  Rollback your migrations, correct the table name in the migration, and re-migrate.  Also make sure your db/seeds.rb and all other files in your codespace have no other references to `Type`.

Comment: wow, i won't make this mistake again! thank you guys!